# How to drag-drop images from one listview to another listview in android

Tags: android

I am preparing app which contains two listview one containing images from sd card ,another listview contains contacts with their default icon ,now i want to drag and drop images from first listview to this another listview of contacts.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private DragListener mDragListener =
                    new DragListener() {

                    int backgroundColor =#f000;// add color of ur choice
                    int defaultBackgroundColor;

                        public void onDrag(int x, int y, ListView listView) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        }

                        public void onStartDrag(View itemView) {
                            itemView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            defaultBackgroundColor = itemView.getDrawingCacheBackgroundColor();
                            itemView.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
                            ImageView iv = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            if (iv != null) iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }

                        public void onStopDrag(View itemView) {
                            itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            itemView.setBackgroundColor(defaultBackgroundColor);
                            ImageView iv = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            if (iv != null) iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                };
```

Create an interface and call its object in ur ListActivity class.Like wise u can drop and Remove

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    final int x = (int) ev.getX();
    final int y = (int) ev.getY();  

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && x < this.getWidth()/4) {
        mDragMode = true;
    }

    if (!mDragMode) 
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mStartPosition = pointToPosition(x,y);
            if (mStartPosition != INVALID_POSITION) {
                int mItemPosition = mStartPosition - getFirstVisiblePosition();
            mDragPointOffset = y - getChildAt(mItemPosition).getTop();
            mDragPointOffset -= ((int)ev.getRawY()) - y;
                startDrag(mItemPosition,y);
                drag(0,y);// replace 0 with x if desired
            }   
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drag(0,y);// replace 0 with x if desired
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        default:
            mDragMode = false;
            mEndPosition = pointToPosition(x,y);
            stopDrag(mStartPosition - getFirstVisiblePosition());
            if (mDropListener != null && mStartPosition != INVALID_POSITION && mEndPosition != INVALID_POSITION) 
                 mDropListener.onDrop(mStartPosition, mEndPosition);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Take the Child ID from the list view then use the on touch event then write the Drag method from the list view.